# Did Tolkien actually use asterisms in the Lord of the Rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, j-r-r-tolkien

I own a version of *The Fellowship of the Ring* that I'm enjoying a lot, and now that I'm nearing the end I thought I might as well buy an ebook on Amazon containing all three books so I can go on with my reading (instead of looking for book 2 and 3 of this one specific edition).

However, I've come across an unexpected obstacle. By skimming through the free Kindle previews that Amazon offers, I've found that *none* of them use asterisms—whereas my copy does. By this, I mean this symbol here:

```
                             *             *             *
```

which is sometimes used to indicate a hard break between paragraphs, with smaller breaks being indicated by a simple empty line between the paragraphs in question. But in every single preview I've read, the empty-line type of break is the only one that is universally used in *all* instances.

So I started wondering: what did Tolkien do? Which version should I go for in order to read a text that is the closest to Tolkien's own use of punctuation?

Comment: It seems like the placed to look would be either his manuscript notes, or the first printings by Allen & Unwin.

Comment: @Labba  I learn something new every day.  I was going to criticize you for writing "asterisms "instdad of "asterisks", but apparently a group of three asterisks is called an asterism.  At first I thought you were asking about the usual meaning of "asterisms" - patterns of stars in the sky.   You should probably edit the question to make it more clear what you ask about.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Sure, feel free to edit the question if you think that will make it easier for other people to understand what I mean! I'd do it, but maybe you already have something in mind regarding how to reword it so I'll let you free to do that.

Comment: The style used in many print Tolkien books is to only uses three asterisks to indicate a section break where it coincides with a page break and to just used a double line break everywhere else. On an ebook there are no page breaks, so they would never use the three asterisks.

Comment: I think the official term for the typographical element is a dinkus

Comment: Note: The backslash produces literal characters in an enormous variety of contexts. Also, did you really mean three asterisks in a row, which is sometimes called a dinkus, or did you mean the more typical asterism (⁂)?

Comment: @Buzz In my facsimile first edition of _The Hobbit_ there are no asterisms or other symbols between paragraphs. Most paragraph breaks have no spacing at all, but there is an occasional paragraph break with an extra line of space, which occur at significant points in the text where you might expect a line of asterisks or some other symbol.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: Yeah, I was ready to answer about how Tolkien referred to the Sickle (Big Dipper for us Americans) in one passage.

Comment: @Adamant - Latest edit makes it far less easy to understand what OP is referring to on the page, so I've rolled it back

Comment: @Valorum - You mean, the edit that lets people see the actual symbol that the question refers to, rather than a some code-formatted stuff that plays merry havoc with text-to-speech?

Comment: How is this an "obstacle"? Such formatting (not punctuation) was almost certainly not specified by Tolkien, but added by the printer.

Comment: @Valorum - I have edited it again in a way that hopefully makes it clear what the symbol is while both actually showing the symbol and respecting the [established guidelines against using code formatting for things other than code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right).

Comment: @Adamant - Except that's not the symbol that OP is referring to. He's referring to a set of three stars that reach across the page, not three stars next to each other like * * *. Since your edit **conflicts with what OP is actually asking**, I'd ask you not to vandalise their answer to suit a rule that doesn't apply

Comment: It's not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPZbQ.jpg), it's [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXP4R.jpg). Big difference

Comment: @Valorum - Then use as many non-breaking space characters as you need to get the length, but don't violate SE policy and break a bunch of tools by using code formatting.

Comment: @Labba Do you have any specific place in your book with these asterisms / dinkus to point, so that we can look at the same place in different editions ?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this is called a [dinkus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinkus). An [asterism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(typography)) is a typographic symbol consisting of three asterisks placed in a triangle (i.e. `⁂`).

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe he used asterisms but cannot say for sure as photos of inside pages of the first edition are incredibly hard to find - probably from owners wanting to keep their originals as pristine as possible. However, looking through what is available, the asterism doesn't seem to align with his style.

Here's a look inside a [first edition](https://www.firstandfine.com/product/tolkien-j-r-r-1955-the-lord-of-the-rings-uk-first-edition-rebind-set-3-2-2-with-original-signed-letter/):

[image]

And a [second edition](https://www.tolkienbookshelf.com/pages/books/2439/j-r-r-tolkien/the-lord-of-the-rings-uk-first-edition-early-impressions-in-custom-leather-slipcase):

[image]

(more images are available through the links.)

For your second question, it's important to note that there were major print errors introduced with the second impression, and many of those issues still show up in print today. So, I would argue that you'll probably never get a version that is a perfect representation of his initial creation.

Additionally, there were 9,250 pages in the original manuscripts. Tolkien intended for the work to be as single and complete piece of literature. However, from the [Lord of the Rings Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings#Publication_history:%7E:text=For%20publication%2C%20the,plus%20six%20appendices)):

> For publication, the work was divided into three volumes to minimize any potential financial loss due to the high cost of type-setting and modest anticipated sales: The Fellowship of the Ring (Books I and II), The Two Towers (Books III and IV), and The Return of the King (Books V and VI plus six appendices).

My final recos:

- For the version closest to his vision but probably furthest from the first impression: Check out a 50th Anniversary Edition single volume version. Concerted efforts were made to correct book errors and provide a version that aligned with Tolkien's initial vision.
- For a reasonably priced version that most closely resembles the initial impression: I'd recommend the [mass market paperback from the 70's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0618640150). (Basing this on timing of release, pagination , and research).

Comment: This aligns with what I found in my facsimile _Hobbit_.   It's likely an Allen and Unwin typesetting style.

Answer (score 3):

### Doesn't seem like it

William Fliss, the Tolkien Archivist at Marquette University (where all of the Lord of the Rings manuscripts are), said in a reddit AMA that he doesn't remember seeing any, though added that he never actively looked for them either.

> **Q. Does Tolkien ever use asterisms is his manuscripts? (i.e. putting a row of three dots to indicate a section break). I think in the published books section breaks are just shown as an extra line break, but how does Tolkien tend to do it in his manuscripts?**
>
> A. Not that I can think of, but I haven't been looking for asterisms either. ... Sorry for the brevity of the response. I am overwhelmed by the number of questions!
> <sub>[I am William Fliss, Tolkien Archivist at Marquette University in Milwaukee. Ask Me Anything!](https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/ycjl1j/i_am_william_fliss_tolkien_archivist_at_marquette/)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I took a quick look and didn't find any in my 1st edition (see picture below). You should point out a specific part of the text where there is a dinkus in you edition if you want me to compare on that specific spot :)

For the rest, I fully agree with [Grokante's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/268262/83605).

[image]

Comment: Such a flex. "Let me check my first edition.... [settles monocle]" :-D